# nginx multiple map conditions on one variable

Tags: nginx, logging, vhosts

I'm trying to exclude both an ip address as well as a user agent from appearing in any of my vhost's logs. Each vhost has its own logfile configured in the respective file. I appended `$if=$variable` to each of the logfile definitions and added this to nginx.conf:

```
map $http_user_agent $variable {
  ~MyUserAgent 0;
  default 1;
}
```

This works. Now I want to add conditions, e.g. an IP address to this variable (without having to change every single vhost's configuration again).

If it's possible to configure this globally, while keeping the different logfile locations that would be a feasable solution as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the logging for each vhost is the same then you dont even need separate files for each hos. You can specify the logging directive at server level and use a variable to create different logs for each vhost

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/$host.log combined;
error_log /var/log/nginx/$host.error.log;
```

You can set your map variable to whatever you like, and you can combine multiple maps to create complex patterns. Instead of having a default value of 1 you could set it to something useful and then include it in your logs.

You can match against more than one variable in a single map, so you could modify your map to exclude your ip from logs by changing it to this:

```
map $http_user_agent$remote_addr $variable {
  ~MyUserAgent 0;
  ~my.ip.ad.dy 0;
  default 1;
}
```

Map evaluation returns as soon as a match is found, so if your map is complex then the order you list your comparison values in is important

Comment: I'm currently more interested in using the varibales for the log files you mentioned first. However, I don't seem to be able to use them. I get files named $host.log (with '$host' actually in the name). Assigning new variables with `set` produces the same behaviour. The variables just are not expanded.